# Cordova build error: Unable to graft xml at selector "/widget/rim:permissions"

Tags: cordova, blackberry, blackberry-10, cordova-cli

Since yesterday I am getting an error at building my `cordova` application for `blackberry10` platform:

```
$ cordova -v
6.5.0
$ cordova build blackberry10
Error: Unable to graft xml at selector "/widget/rim:permissions" from "...\platforms\blackberry10\www\config.xml" during config install
```

There is already a relating bug report on their JIRA [CB-12480](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-12480), but I still found no solution…

Comment: With `cordova@6.1.1` the error does not occur, but with all major versions…

Answer (score 0):

Adding and removing platforms solved this for me. Used commands:

`cordova platform remove blackberry`

Then

`cordova platform add blackberry`